# Replace Checkpoint VPN client by Windows 8/7 built-in client

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, vpn

Hi I'm running the [Check point Endpoint Security VPN R75 (which replaces SecureClient) for Windows](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal/user/anon/page/default.psml/media-type/html?action=portlets.DCFileAction&eventSubmit_doGetdcdetails=&fileid=11611) and it crashes my laptop very often.
Now I've fixed it and due to the crashes I upgraded to Windows 8.

Long story short, I don't want to go though that process anymore.
I want to use the built-in Windows 8 VPN client to connect to the Network which works by using the Checkpoit VPN software.

Steps I've taken

1. I have already enrolled and saved certificate (.p12).
2. Added/imported the certificate to my local profile
3. Followed the XP part of this [thread](https://forums.checkpoint.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=32897)
4. See screenshots for the configs
   [image: Security tab]
   [image: Security tab advanced settings]
   [image: Security tab smartcard or certification properties]

Hopefully I can get some help configuring this without the use of Checkpoint VPN.

Comment: See if [this note](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/vpn_client500_501/release/notes/51client.html#wp1346340) applies to your case.

Answer (score -1):

```
ctrl+alt+suppr
Execute
certmgr.msc
```

And then "Request New Certificate" and you follow what is needed for your certificate/token/smartcard

Comment: I've already created the certificate and it's already installed.

Comment: Incomprehensible gibberish